# SQL subquery with description

Tags: sql, subquery

the code:

```
 select code, description from table_a  where prize = (select max(prize) from  table_a)
```

I want the result is the description along with the code of the highest prize from its category.
[image]

So the result will be

[image]

How to do the subquery for this problem?

Comment: What have you done so far? Post whatever you have tried and then may be we talk.. :D

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a homework completion service. Your instructor gave you the assignment, not us, and you're going to need to do your own work. If we do it for you, you don't learn anything. If you can't get started, ask your teacher for help; they're being paid to teach you. Good luck.

Comment: I can do it for 1 result.. but I want the result per category. I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty close. try this one.

```
select 
       code, 
       description 
from table_a a 
  where 
     prize = (select max(prize) from  table_a b where b.code = a.code)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should compare with two table_a tables.

Try something like this

select a.code, a.description, b.code,b.description
from table_a a INNER JOIN table_a b
ON a.code=b.code 
Where..